# Create a very thin conky window?

Tags: conky

I am currently attempting to configure my Conky layout. I would like a very thin panel behind the text to go across a portion of my screen (something like 20 pixels high by 400 pixels wide).

Having fiddled with some settings, I can't seem to get the panel behind the text thin enough in the y-direction (things are fine in the x-direction, with the panel hugging the text closely). There seems to be about a ~5 to 6 pixel buffer above and below the text item. Note the buffer above and below the date text:

[image]

I commented out the text item itself, and it still displayed improperly.

I changed the `border_inner_margin` setting to 0 as well (and tried some other smaller values) to no avail.

Here is the .conkyrc file:

```
own_window yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,skip_taskbar
background no
double_buffer yes
use_spacer no
use_xft yes
update_interval 3.0
draw_shades yes
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
uppercase no
border_width 0
border_inner_margin 0
default_color white
default_shade_color black
default_outline_color white
own_window_colour black
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_argb_value 80
alignment top_right
gap_x 0
gap_y 0
override_utf8_locale no
xftfont Terminus:size=8
xftalpha 0.8

TEXT

${offset 0}${color }${time %a, } ${color }${time %e %B %G}
```

Comment: Could you add the minimal version of your config file to your post so we understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is quite simply that conky is taking literally what you provided in the `TEXT` section, and that is 3 lines of text! Simply remove the blank lines before and after your wanted output commands.